# What's the difference between expires, max-age, and shared max-age?

Tags: caching, http-caching

I have never used **HTTP Caching**.

I found those caching options on [Symfony documentation page](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/cache.html).

I just wanted to know what's the difference between `expires`, `max-age`, and `s-maxage` headers?

Answer (score 13):

Shortly: `Expires` is understand by **HTTP/1.0** agents, whereas `Cache-control: max-age=` was introduced in **HTTP/1.1**. `s-maxage` is similar to max-age but it applies to proxies instead of clients.

Answer (score 2):

- **Cache-Control**:

  Was introduced in HTTP/1.1 and supersedes previous headers (e.g. **Expires**) used to define response caching policies. All modern browsers support Cache-Control, hence that is all we will need.
- **Expires**:

  While the Cache-Control header turns on client-side caching and sets the max-age of a resource, the Expires header is used to specify a specific point in time the resource is no longer valid.
- **max-age**:

  Used on both **client** and **proxy** for content expiration
- **s-maxage**:

  Used only by the **proxy** for content expiration